# Auto incrementing unique url

Tags: php, regex, string

I am looking to create an auto incrementing unique string using PHP, containing [a-Z 0-9] starting at 2 chars long and growing when needed.

This is for a url shrinker so each string (or alias) will be saved in the database attached to a url.

Any insight would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: How do I increment 'az'? 'b0' I suppose?

Comment: *(suggested reading)* [Sean Coates blogs: Arbitrary Incrementer in PHP](http://seancoates.com/blogs/arbitrary-incrementer-in-php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an implementation of an `incr` function which takes a string containing characters [0-9a-zA-Z] and increments it, pushing a 0 onto the front if required using the 'carry-the-one' method.

```
<?php

function incr($num) {
  $chars = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
  $parts = str_split((string)$num);

  $carry = 1;
  for ($i = count($parts) - 1; $i >= 0 && $carry; --$i) {
    $value = strpos($chars, $parts[$i]) + 1;
    if ($value >= strlen($chars)) {
      $value = 0;
      $carry = 1;
    } else {
      $carry = 0;
    }
    $parts[$i] = $chars[$value];
  }

  if ($carry)
    array_unshift($parts, $chars[0]);

  return implode($parts);
}

$num = '0';
for ($i = 0; $i < 1000; ++$i) {
  echo $num = incr($num), "\n";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

*Note this solution won't produce uppercase letters.*

Use [`base_convert()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.base-convert.php) to convert to base 36, which will use [a-z0-9].

```
<?php
// outputs a, b, c, ..., 2o, 2p, 2q
for ($i = 10; $i < 99; ++$i)
  echo base_convert($i, 10, 36), "\n";
```

Given the last used number, you can convert it back to an integer with [`intval()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.intval.php) increment it and convert the result back to base 36 with `base_convert()`.

```
<?php

$value = 'bc9z';
$value = intval($value, 36);
++$value;
$value = base_convert($value, 10, 36);
echo $value; // bca0

// or
echo $value = base_convert(intval($value, 36) + 1, 10, 36);
```

Comment: +1 But beware in systems with 32-bit ints, you will start getting into trouble after 2^31-1=2 147 483 647

Answer (score 0):

If your string was single case rather than mixed, and didn't contain numerics, then you could literally just increment it:

```
$testString="AA";
for($x = 0; $x < 65536; $x++) {
    echo $testString++.'<br />';
}

$testString="aa";
for($x = 0; $x < 65536; $x++) {
    echo $testString++.'<br />';
}
```

But you could possibly make some use of this feature even with a mixed alphanumeric string

Comment: Nit-picky point of annoyance: Don't use string concatenation with `echo`, use commas: `echo $teststring++, '<br />';`

Answer (score 0):

To expand on meagar's answer, here is how you can do it with uppercase letters as well and for number arbitrarily big (requires the [bcmath extension](http://php.net/bcmath), but you could as well use gmp or the bigintegers pear package):

```
function base10ToBase62($number) {
    static $chars = "0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
    $result = "";
    $n = $number;
    do {
        $remainder = bcmod($n, 62);
        $n = bcdiv($n, 62);
        $result = $chars[$remainder] . $result;
    } while ($n > 0);

    return $result;
}

for ($i = 10; $i < 99; ++$i) {
    echo base10ToBase62((string) $i), "\n";
}
```